# How can I make a horizontal pickerView with collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipickerview

How can I make a horizontal UICollectionView with pickerView effect? I have already created the horizontal UICollectionView. Now I want to apply the UIPickerView effect on it.

Here is the image where i wanted to make that effect(UIPickerView effect):

[image]

Here is my ViewControllerCode -

```
import UIKit

class WalletViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var walletImage: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "WalletCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "walletCollectionViewCell")
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "walletCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! WalletCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by pickerview effect? Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: When someone scroll the collectionView, the ** center** image will show clearly and it will be zoomed and other images will be in blur without zooming effect.

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). Hope this fits your requirment.

Comment: @MdRashedPervez That is not pickerView Effect. It is called as carousel effect. You can easily find third party libraries for the same. Try https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Use icrousel as specified by surjeet or use this [Horizontal picker view](https://github.com/akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift)

Comment: Thanks @VishalSonawane

Comment: @MdRashedPervez You are welcome :)